# How to find the occurrences of a column mapped to a corresponding column in a query SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query as below

```
select custref, tetranumber 
from
    (select * 
     from cdsheader h, custandaddr c 
     where h.custref=c.cwdocid and c.addresstype = 'C' )
where tetranumber = '034096'
```

The objective is the 2nd column should have only one corresponding 1st column

Ex : 034096 should have always have 2600135 as the first column

I would like to check if there is any value apart from 2600135  for 034096.

(I am a java developer and suggested a solution to avoid 1 to n or n to n mappings of data but there is a bad data already in the DB(Oracle), so I would like to check whether there is a bad data so that I could delete the data)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard **20 years ago** - time to stop using this!

Comment: Also, even in subqueries, it's probably a bad idea to use `SELECT *`.  For one thing, if the columns you list are all in an index, the results _may_ be returned using the index, instead of also looking at the table (RDBMS dependent, and if the optimizer can get equivalent information from the final `SELECT` clause anyways).

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... it would be very helpful to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response guys,

I have figured out the way and here it goes...

select custref, count(distinct(tetranumber)) from(
select custref, tetranumber from cdsheader h, custandaddr c where h.custref=c.cwdocid and c.addresstype = 'C')
group by custref having count(distinct(tetranumber))>1

Answer (score 0):

re: *The objective is the 2nd column should have only one corresponding 1st column*
You'll need to perform an aggregate function, like MAX or MIN, to determine which of the row is returned.